# Keyboard shortcut in Flash Builder to insert ASDoc comment

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

Is there a keyboard command to insert ASDoc comment in ActionScript?

Before:

```
|
public var width:Number;
```

After:

```
/**
* |
* */
public var width:Number;
```

The pipe character representing the cursor location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer partly.

Command + SHIFT + D will insert:

```
/**
* 
*/
```

This is not formatted the way I was hoping and it inserts whitespace at the end. So I do not mark this solved but merely a step closer.

Comment: I wonder if [code templates](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5344c6f711358acdda1d-7fff.html#WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-3de79aff12e6bf94e34-7fff) might be useful here?

Comment: In Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates > Comments are comment templates but I think they're only for Java because I've updated them (and restarted) and there is no change.

Comment: I was looking at FB4 at work and it lacks this feature that is present under FB4.6. It's under Preferences > Flash Builder > Editors > Code Templates > ActionScript. I don't think it will be as useful as cmd+shift+d as that command will also add the `@param` and `@return` ASDoc comments where applicable. Maybe follow cmd+shift+d with a "[Remove Trailing Whitespace](http://bimalesh.blogspot.com/2010/02/remove-trailing-white-spaces-in-eclipse.html)"?

Comment: Oh nice. I added a template named, "asdoc" and it works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can update the ASDoc templates text from Flash builder 4.6.
Window->Preferences-> ASDoc Generation.
In this window you can edit the template text to be inserted for functions/Properties/Classes as you required.

For inserting this ASDoc templates in source code, place the cursor on the element for which you want to generate the ASDoc and use Alt+SHift+J key combination.